# Autoindex ¿en false o true? Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Estoy probando por primera vez los `index` en `mongoose` y leyendo la documentación me encuentro con este [párrafo](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes).

> Cuando se inicia su aplicación, `Mongoose` llama automáticamente
>   `createIndex` a cada índice definido en su esquema. `Mongoose` llamará
>   `createIndex` a cada índice secuencialmente y emitirá un evento `index`
>   en el modelo cuando todas las `createIndex` llamadas se hayan realizado
>   correctamente o cuando haya un error. Si bien es bueno para el
>   desarrollo, se recomienda deshabilitar este comportamiento en la
>   producción, ya que la creación de índices puede causar un impacto
>   significativo en el rendimiento . Deshabilite el comportamiento
>   estableciendo la `autoIndex` opción de su esquema en `false`, o globalmente
>   en la conexión estableciendo la opción `autoIndex` en false.

El problema es que no entiendo el efecto de setear el `autoindex` en `false` o `true`, digamos ¿Que hace?.

Si se coloca en `false`, leí en otras preguntas que hay que indexar de forma manual cuando se crean nuevos datos en la `BD`, si es así ¿Como se hace?

Gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La opción [`autoIndex`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#autoIndex) en [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com) viene establecida a `true` por defecto, ya que viene pensada para que puedas realizar el desarrollo y las pruebas en primer lugar, antes de poner tu aplicación o desarrollo en producción.

**Pero, ¿qué significa realmente dicha opción?**

Pues cuando se crea un [*Schema*](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) con *Mongoose*, y en el mismo, hemos establecido algún (o algunos) campo(s) como [índice](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes) para el Modelo dentro de la colección; al momento de establecer satisfactoriamente la conexión, se hace una llamada (internamente) a un método llamado [`createIndexes()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/createIndexes/#dbcmd.createIndexes) de MongoDB. Este método se encarga de generar los índices de nuestros documentos en la colección a la que apunta nuestro *Schema*.

Cuando trabajamos en un entorno de desarrollo, normalmente tenemos algunos datos de ejemplo y pruebas, y no sucede nada al crear índices para unos pocos documentos en algunos cientos o miles de colecciones que disponga nuestra base de datos de desarrollo.

Sin embargo, no sucede lo mismo en un entorno de producción, donde posiblemente la data sea bastante densa.

Siempre está la duda: *¿pero qué pasa si mi base de datos no existe y esta es la primera implementación?*

Igualmente, aunque sea la primera implementación, en algún momento necesitarás realizar algún ajuste, adiciones o cambios a tu aplicación, y cuando la vuelvas a implementar sobre la base de datos que ya está en producción, pues se verá afectado el rendimiento si no cambias la opción de `autoIndex` a `false`, ya que se ejecutará el proceso de indexado sobre todos los documentos de la colección o colecciones afectadas por el cambio, aunque el mismo parezca trivial.

**Índices, o la fábula de [Esopo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esopo) sobre [*La Liebre y la Tortuga*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_liebre_y_la_tortuga)**

Los índices son nuestros amigos a la hora de buscar cualquier información almacenada en algún sitio (una base de datos, por ejemplo). Imagina tener que encontrar el número de teléfono de un contacto en particular, pero sin contar con un índice de contactos, simplemente se tiene la lista cronológica de los contactos según fueron añadidos al directorio. Para hallar un contacto habría que recorrer la lista hasta hallar el contacto deseado.

Es por esto que se crea un índice de contactos, donde los mismos se pueden ordenar alfabéticamente. De esta forma es mucho más fácil encontrar un registro almacenado en nuestra lista de contactos.

Los índices nos ayudan en dicha tarea, y MongoDB te permite implementar índices sobre campos específicos de tus documentos en una colección, para que las búsquedas sobre estos campos sean más eficientes.

Pero para que estos índices sean de utilidad, debe realizarse un proceso conocido como [*indexado*](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/indexar) para clasificar y ordenar estos datos de tal forma que podamos acceder a los mismos de una forma eficiente.

Por ejemplo, el índice de un libro nos permite acceder a la información de un tema específico, ya que simplemente nos dirige a la página del libro donde se encuentra dicha información. De lo contrario tendríamos que leer parte del libro hasta encontrar lo que buscamos o necesitamos.

Ahora imagina que mientras estamos buscando la información en el libro sin índice, se empieza a escribir el índice del mismo. Debemos parar nuestra la lectura, ya que en el proceso el libro comienza a ordenarse desde el principio para añadir las entradas en el índice. Por cada página procesada tarda una razonable cantidad de tiempo, digamos 2 segundos, pero resulta que el libro tiene 1500 páginas, lo cual resulta en 3 mil segundos, que es casi 1 hora (50 minutos para ser exactos). Eso no sería muy agradable.

Entonces, es por ello que en un entorno de producción, es más eficiente realizar el indexado de la información en momentos en los que la base de datos se encuentre en un estado de poca actividad, para evitar demoras en las respuestas a los procesos de nuestra aplicación o aplicaciones que requieren de la base de datos.

Tal como la liebre de la fábula, nos podemos ver tentados a realizar el indexado al momento de crear o cargar nuestro *Schema*, al fin y al cabo, el indexado hay que hacerlo en algún momento y esto es un atajo para no hacerlo luego. Una muy astuta jugada.

Pero resulta que un proceso de indexado consume recursos del servidor de base de datos que pueden ser críticos para el desempeño de todo el sistema. Al final, te puedes encontrar en un atasco, del cual no podrás salir hasta que el proceso de indexado finalice, ya que si lo detienes abruptamente, no quiero imaginar los resultados.

Es por ello, que tal como la tortuga, debemos ser relajados en esta situación. Y programar el indexado para algún momento en que el impacto de dicho proceso no sea tan severo. Así al hacer la implementación de tu aplicación, la misma estará casi inmediatamente disponible para su uso y no estará atorada en un indexado absurdo.

En este caso, gana nuevamente la tortuga, como en la fábula. Y es que aunque nos parezca tedioso realizar el proceso de indexado en otro momento, realmente es por una buena razón: la eficiencia.

**¿Cómo indexar los nuevos documentos?**

Pues como ya vamos suponiendo, debemos usar herramientas para administrar nuestra base de datos ([Mongo Shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/), [RoboMongo](https://robomongo.org/), [MongoDB for NodeJS Driver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb), etc.). Con dichas herramientas podemos ejecutar el proceso de indexado de nuestra información.

Existen muchas formas de hacerlo, pero todas van a implementar de alguna forma el método [`createIndexes()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/createIndexes/).

Un ejemplo:

```js
// el siguiente código realiza el indexado sobre la colección 'users'
// en la base de datos 'myAwesomeDB'
//
// se indexa el campo 'email' como índice de tipo 'text'
// se establece el índice como 'unique'
// se le da el nombre de 'emailIndex' al índice

db.getSiblingDB("myAwesomeDB").runCommand(
  {
    createIndexes: "users",
    indexes: [
        {
            key: {
                email: "text",
            },
            name: "emailIndex",
            unique: true
        }
    ]
  }
)
```

**¿Cuándo debo realizar el indexado?**

Tan pronto como tu implementación lo permita y de acuerdo a los requerimientos de los clientes que necesiten la información de la base de datos.

Recuerda que la [documentación](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-creation/#index-build-impact-on-database-performance) de MongoDB sugiere (traducción propia):

> Realizar el indexado en momentos en que la colección afectada tiene una alta carga de escritura, puede producir una reducción en el rendimiento de la escritura y alargar el tiempo para el proceso de indexado.
>
> Considere programar un tiempo de servicio (mantenimiento) durante el cual la aplicación se detenga o la carga de escritura sea mínima sobre la colección. Inicie el proceso de indexado durante este tiempo de servicio para reducir el potencial impacto negativo de dicho proceso.

Comment: el autoIndex es un metodo de mongoose para crear el indice, de igual forma se puede hacer indice en MongoDB(como lo dice la respuesta) ideal que siempre conozca el motor y/o lenguaje de programacion y luego la libreria/addons/plugins

Comment: Hola, primero que nada gracias por la explicacion. En la documentacion de mongoose muestran la linea para llamar a createIndex():

animalSchema.index({ name: 1, type: -1 });

Y en mongo Shell :

db.myColl.createIndex( { category: 1 }, { collation: { locale: "fr" } } )

¿Estas dos lineas hacen lo mismo, llaman a createIndex en que momento con autoIndex en false?
Si coloco autoIndex en false, no me queda claro como y en que momento llamar a que se creen.

Disculpa la tardanza como comento Jack, lei la documentacion de mongoDB primero.

Comment: No son la misma cosa. El método [`index()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes) del esquema se usa cuando es **necesario** crear [índices compuestos](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/). Por lo tanto esa línea que colocas establece un índice compuesto por los campos `name` y `type` del esquema, siendo uno de orden ascendente (1) y otro descendente (-1). Este método de Mongoose llamará al método [`createIndex()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#createIndex) del driver de MongoDB para NodeJS: `createIndex({name:1, type:-1},...)`.

Comment: Si has establecido la opción a `false`, nunca se llamará al método `createIndex()`, ni aunque hagas uso del método `index()` del esquema. El Shell de Mongo trabaja directamente sobre la BD y no tiene nada que ver con Mongoose, mi respuesta se basa en el uso de Mongoose, no del Shell de Mongo. **No me queda claro cómo y en qué momento llamar a que se creen**, pues debes llamar a crear índices tal como explico en mi respuesta, no desde Mongoose, sino desde el Shell de Mongo, cuando el Servidor (producción) tenga menos carga. En modo `dev` no es necesario colocar `autoIndex: false`.