# Como utilizar dos foreign keys como primary key en MongoDB

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, nosql

Estoy realizando una aplicacion en la que les permito a los usuarios seguir otros usuarios. Por lo tanto tengo una colección Usuario:

```
name:{
    type: String,
    unique: false,
    require: [true, 'El nombre es requerido']
},
email:{
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    require: [true, 'El email es requerido']
},
password:{
    type: String,
    require: [true, 'El password es requerido']
},
public_date:{
    type: Date,
    required: [true, 'La fecha de creacion es requerida']
},
update_date:{
    type: Date,
    required: false
},
state:{
    type: Boolean,
    require: [true, 'El estado es requerido']
}
```

Y una colección Tracing:

```
follower:{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Usuario',
    require: true
},
following:{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Usuario',
    require: true
},
public_date:{
    type: Date
}
```

El problema que tengo es que puedo igresar multiples documentos con el mismo valor following y follower que otros documentos, por lo tanto tengo que un mismo usuario puede estar "siguiendo" varias veces a un mismo usuario.

En SQL se puede utilizar following y follower como primary key,  mi pregunta es, ¿aquí se puede realizar algo similar?

**PD:** He leido que se puede crear un Object con los atributos following y follower y definir este objeto como unico, realice esa prueba pero tengo problemas a la hora de devolver todos los documentos de un follower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

el tipo de indice que necesitas se le conoce como indice compuesto.

Lo que tendrías que hacer es crear el indice de la siguiente manera:

```
db.Tracing.ensureIndex({"follower": 1, "following": -1})
```

De esta manera el indice que se generará, agrupará los datos primero por el campo follower y luego por el campo following.

Espero te sirva esta información

Comment: Gracias @Pillo por responder, queria consultarte si hay alguna diferencia entre el metodo index y ensureIndexes. Estaba leyendo en la documentacion de que estos metodos afectan fuertemente el rendimiento de la base de datos, por lo tanto, ¿es una buena practica utilizar estos metodos en produccion?

Comment: Perdon tienes ensureIndex ya fue depreciado desde la version 3.0 me parece. Se debe usar createInfex

Comment: @Doormut en relación a tu duda sobre la creación de índices en producción, puedes leer [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/327253/autoindex-en-false-o-true-mongoose/328260#328260) respuesta donde hablo un poco al respecto. Saludos

Comment: Gracias @MauricioContreras por responder, muy bueno tu aporte. Lei tu respuesta y me genero la siguiente duda: ¿tengo que definir luego de mi Schema el index? por ejemplo: tracingSchema.index({ follower: 1, following: -1 }); o esto lo tengo que realizar periódicamente a través de el Shell de mongo?